# Kotlin check List contain ignore case

Tags: list, kotlin, contains, ignore-case

Having the equals ignore case option

```
 if (bookType.equals(Type.BABY.name, true))
```

Is there an option to do contain similar with ignore case?

```
 val validTypes = listOf("Kids", "Baby")

 if (validTypes.contains(bookType)))
```

I see there is an option of doing :

```
  if (bookType.equals(Type.BABY.name, true) || bookType.equals(Type.KIDS.name, true))
```

But I want more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

Could use the [`is` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#is-and-is-operators) with a [`when` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression), and directly with `book` rather than `bookType`:

```kotlin
val safetyLevel = when (book) {
    is Type.BABY, is Type.KIDS -> "babies and kids"
    is Type.CHILD -> "okay for children"
    else -> "danger!"
}
```

See [Type checks and casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make the valid types list all uppercase then you can do the following:

You could use `map` to convert the case for all items in the list e.g.

```kotlin
validTypes.contains(bookType.uppercase())
```

Or you could use any (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html)

```kotlin
validTypes.any { bookType.uppercase() == it }
```

If you want to keep the casing of your original list you could do:

```kotlin
validTypes.any { bookType.replaceFirstChar { it.uppercaseChar() } == it }
```